# Google directions api zero_results only on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-volley

I've builded a simple app in Android where I use Google Maps directions api.
In my code I make a Volley request and it works, but almost always it response ZERO_RESULTS.
But if I copy the value of the uri and I paste it into browser, it response some result.

Here is my code

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String uri = null;
    uri = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?" +
            "origin=" + partenza + "&" +
            "destination=" + arrivo +
            "&waypoints=optimize:true";


    for(int i = 0; i<tappe.size();i++){
        uri = uri.concat("|").concat(tappe.get(i));
    }


    uri = uri + "&key=" + getString(R.string.google_maps_key);
    uri = Uri.parse(uri).buildUpon()
            .build().toString();


    JsonObjectRequest stringRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.POST, uri, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
                JSONArray cast = obj.getJSONArray("routes");
                if(obj.getString("status").equals("ZERO_RESULTS")){
                    Toast.makeText(TragittoActivity.this, "Impossibile trovare soluzione", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                }
                for (int i=0; i<cast.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject news = cast.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONArray legs = news.getJSONArray("legs");

                    for (int j=0; j<legs.length(); j++) {
                        String start = legs.getJSONObject(j).getString("start_address");
                        String end = legs.getJSONObject(j).getString("end_address");

                    }

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("VolleyError", error.toString());
        }

    }) {

    };
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

How can I resolve this problem?
Are any differences between web call and Android call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue looks to be related to the call format:

1. Try parsing the URI "manually" (like replacing the spaces with "%20" using the `replace` function) instead of using the `Uri.Parse` function.
2. Try getting the response as a string instead of JSON: instead of using a `JsonObjectRequest` use a `StringRequest` and then converting the string to a `JSONObject`
3. Since you are passing the parameters in the URL and you are setting the method parameters to `null`, try using a `GET` method instead of `POST`